# awk + export value to awk

Tags: awk

the following program needs to print the words

```
First 

Second 

Third
```

But because i parameter from awk not get the value from “for” loop its print all words:

```
     First second third
     First second third
     First second third
```

How to fix awk in order to print first the “first” word second the “second” word and so on

THX

Yael

```
 program:

 for i in 1 2 3
 do
 echo "first second third" | awk '{print $i}'
 done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change you code like this:

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
 echo "first second third" | awk -v i=$i '{print $i}'
done
```

To use the variable 'i' from the shell.

You can also just change the record separator (RS) to have the same result :

```
echo "first second third" | awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "} {print $1}'
```

But I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: It's better not to use the quote-unquote-quote method because it's hard to read. This, which uses awk's variable passing, is better: `awk -v i=$i '{print $i}'`

Comment: You are definitely right `echo "first second third" | awk '{print $'${i}'}'` was not a good solution. So I edited the answer to follow your method.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
for a in First Second Third
do
    awk 'BEGIN { print ARGV[1] }' $a
done
```

Or you could do:

```
for a in First Second Third
do
    awk -v arg=$a 'BEGIN { print arg }'
done
```

Answer (score 2):

don't do the unnecessary. the shell for loop is not needed! Just do it with awk!

`$ echo "first second third" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'`

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use:

```
echo "first second third" | awk -F " " -v OFS="\n"  '{print $1,$2,$3}'
```